# Is there any way to send RPC to other nodes without creating your own node?

Tags: node, rpc, public-node

I am wondering if there is a way to send RPC to other nodes without creating your own node because I do not have enough capacity to create a node in my laptop. Below is what I have tried.

Got some ips from https://tezos.giganode.io/ and ran `curl -s [IP:Port]/version`, but nothing responded.
Got some ips with https://services.tzkt.io/v1/network?state=running&p=$page&n=50 and ran the same curl command, but nothing responded.

Thanks,

Comment: What RPC commands are you needing to send to other nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SmartPy Nodes](https://mainnet.smartpy.io/)

`curl https://carthagenet.smartpy.io/version` should work fine

Comment: Thanks! @RoMarQ
Also do you know how to get the list of the nodes we can send RPC like the SmartPy one? I would like to know as many nodes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The tezos-node daemon blocks RPC by default to the public. Additionally, most public RPC servers limit which RPCs you can access because some can be very CPU/memory intensive.